# Review improvement

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes when you click on a review, it takes you to an answer that way below the 'fold'. If you have to read the question to get into context, you have to go up, and basically lose the answer you're reviewing.

Would it be a good idea to show only the question and the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you review an answer, and you click on "review answer," you already see the question for which the answer has been given.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

It is probable you don't see all the question's text; in that case, you grab the knob that is between the question and the answer, drag it on the bottom, and you see the full question.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: OK, my bad, I always click on the link and never saw the [review answer] button :-(